# Qt Android and Native Date/TimePickerDialog Appear Different

Tags: java, android, c++, qt

I wrote Date/TimePickerDialog code in Android/Java. Then when I ran this code with Android Studio on Android 6.0, I see: [Android Native Image](https://s28.postimg.org/7ngf5yf19/phone_android_1.jpg). Then when I ran this code in `Qt` / C++, I see: [Android Qt Image](https://s29.postimg.org/9ndc0vtg7/phone_qt_1.jpg). Java native code is same but Android native and Qt are differents. Also test device is same (Android 6.0 Phone). Why is different same code is running with Android native and `Qt`?

***Picker.java***:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Context;

public class Picker extends org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity
{
    private static Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    private static String date, time;
    private static Context c;

    public Picker()
    {
    }

    public static String datePickerDialog(Context context)
    {
        c = context;
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(c,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                        date = i2 + "/" + i1 + "/" + i;
                        Toast.makeText(c, date, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        datePickerDialog.show();

        return date;
    }

    public static String timePickerDialog(Context context)
    {
        c = context;
        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(c,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int i, int i1) {
                        time = i + " : " + i1;
                        Toast.makeText(c, time, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false);
        timePickerDialog.show();

        return time;
    }
}
```

***My test.h file***:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtAndroid>
#include <QAndroidJniObject>

class Test : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit Test(QObject* parent = 0);
  Q_INVOKABLE QString datePickerDialog() const;
  Q_INVOKABLE QString timePickerDialog() const;

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif
```

***My test.cpp file***:

```
#include "test.h"

Test::Test(QObject* parent) : QObject(parent)
{
}

QString Test::datePickerDialog() const
{
  QAndroidJniObject datePickerDialog;
  QtAndroid::runOnAndroidThread([&]()
  {
    datePickerDialog = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod(
        "com/xxx/qttest/Picker",
        "datePickerDialog",
        "(Landroid/content/Context;)Ljava/lang/String;",
        QtAndroid::androidActivity().object());
  });

  return datePickerDialog.toString();
}

QString Test::timePickerDialog() const
{
  QAndroidJniObject timePickerDialog;
  QtAndroid::runOnAndroidThread([&]()
  {
    timePickerDialog = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod(
        "com/xxx/qttest/Picker",
        "timePickerDialog",
        "(Landroid/content/Context;)Ljava/lang/String;",
        QtAndroid::androidActivity().object());
  });

  return timePickerDialog.toString();
}
```

Comment: Because com/xxx/qttest/Picker and android.app.DatePickerDialog are different controls?

Comment: No different controls, I am using ***Picker.java*** file in `Android Studio` and `Qt`. But you see ***Picker.java*** is running different with `Android Studio` and `Qt`.

Comment: Are you sure you are using same Android SDK versions and appcompat libraries in both cases

Comment: When I created Android project on `Android Studio`, the project sdk version is API 15. When I created `Qt Quick Controls 2 Application` project, the project sdk version is minimum sdk version API 24 and target sdk version API 24.

Comment: Don't you want to align them

Comment: I want calendar such as Android native (look at [Image](https://s28.postimg.org/7ngf5yf19/phone_android_1.jpg)), but for `Qt`. How can I do?